# How to use CAS authentication with angular2 webpack starter typescript?

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, cas

I am using the following:

```
https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter
```

I start the application with `npm start` that uses webpack dev server. My issue is I want to add CAS authentication, but have no idea where what goes. This is the library I am trying to use:

```
https://github.com/TencentWSRD/connect-cas2
```

All the examples appear to use express, though I am not sure if I can use this with the webpack-dev-server as is with the starter I am using? If so, how do I use it? Or do I need a different CAS library that is compatible with the npm start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack is  more of a build tool with minimal server capability. It can serve static content making it perfect for updating content on the fly and put together simple websites with basic routing and client side side logic.

If you want anything even a little more complex you will need a server side technology. So the connect-cas2 will require you to use node.js and express. The documentation shows you exactly how to set it up.

I don't know anything about connect-cas2 but I know passport for authentication, but they wouldn't be terribly different. I would follow the quick start and if you have any issues then edit your question with the code that you are having issues with or have trouble understanding.

I have been digging around and you might be able to proxy the authentication if you already have a CAS server setup somewhere. I would try the following:

```
// the proxy option is part of the devServer in your webpack.config.js
devServer: {
    contentBase: 'public',

    // setup a proxy
    proxy: {
        // just replace the /cas/validate endpoint to the endpoint in your 
        // website that will trigger the api call
        '/cas/validate': 'https://url-to-your-cas-server.com'
    }
},
```

Comment: The documentation is very clear for connect-cas2, I guess my issue now is how I can use express using the default starter project in my OP https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter. I know "config/webpack.dev.js" has some endpoint/express stuff, but it is not directly usable with connect-cas2.

Comment: Webpack doesn't use express, it's built on the Common.js library. When you configure the div server you are actually building a basic express server and using webpack as middleware to "watch" and build your front end project.

Comment: I attempted to get the webpack to use express, but am getting hung up. If there is some insight you might have on this, that would be great. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48069757/how-to-use-express-with-gdi2290-angular-starter-to-be-able-to-add-custom-express

Comment: So you are still not actually getting webpack to use express, instead you will want to integrate webpack into express. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996128/webpack-dev-server-throws-error-refused-to-execute-script-because-its-mime-typ/48054492#48054492) is another question I answered.

Comment: You just need to configure a proxy in webpack, you start your express server and then use the proxy to forward your requests to your local express folder for development.

Comment: Wait so I don't actually need to have any cas plugin to be able to plug CAS into webpack? The server is just smart enough to autheticate to cas by specifying /cas/validate into the endpoint? That would be ideal!

Comment: `/cas/validate` can be replaced with the actual endpoint on the server that is using CAS but you need to specify the base url for the server in the proxy.

Comment: In need of the same feature, were you able to get it working ?